# Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka Streams binder) application can't sustain more than one processor

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

We have written a basic streams processor using Spring Cloud Stream (3.0.9.RELEASE) and the Kafka streams binder. The actual project contains multiple classes annotated with @SpringBootApplication, each with their own functions, but only one is used at a time.

The issue we're having is that, when bundling our app into a JAR and running it as a k8s deployment, if we run any more than 1 replica at a time, those additional replicas terminate after a few minutes with no meaningful error message or obvious reason why. For example, if we run 5 replicas, 1 will stay up indefinitely and process events, but the other 4 (although they too initially start to process events) will exit shortly after. Obviously if we set our deployment to run only 1 replica there is no issue, but the processor needs to be scalable.

This [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_application_id) of the documentation regarding setting an application ID seems relevant:

```
For production deployments, it is highly recommended to explicitly specify the application ID
through configuration. This is especially going to be very critical if you are auto scaling your
application in which case you need to make sure that you are deploying each instance with the
same application ID.
```

but neither setting this value at the binding level (for our normalize function):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            functions:
              normalize:
                applicationId: normalizer-full
```

nor setting it at the binder level:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            applicationId: normalizer-full
```

seems to be able to keep the subsequent pods running.

Any help appreciated.

-- EDIT --

Here is a capture of the trace logging When the processor shuts down after several minutes:

```
2020-11-20 06:32:09.721 DEBUG 1 --- [extShutdownHook] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@34f7cfd9, started on Fri Nov 20 06:26:59 GMT 2020
2020-11-20 06:32:09.722 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.722 DEBUG 1 --- [extShutdownHook] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5e1dde44, started on Fri Nov 20 06:27:23 GMT 2020, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@34f7cfd9
2020-11-20 06:32:09.722 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.723 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@38830ea: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,KStreamBinderConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinderFactory,org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata,org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.MultiBinderPropertiesConfiguration,provisioningProvider,kStreamBinder]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7cb502c
2020-11-20 06:32:09.723 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory': [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 TRACE 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stream-builder-normalize'
2020-11-20 06:32:09.724 DEBUG 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483547
...
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on. You don't see anything in the logs? How about Kafka logs? There has to be something that points to whats going on. Your approach of setting the application-id at the functions level seems correct to me (binder level won't work since you have multiple functions on the classpath). Nothing is obvious to me that indicates that it has to do anything with the application-id. If you can share more configs, detailed steps to reproduce, then we can probably look further.

Comment: @sobychacko I've added a section of trace logging, but I'm not sure how much context it adds. I can't see anything in the kafka broker logs that relate to the processor, or why all replicas except for one are repeatedly shutting down.